# May I modify my panel's children's width?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I imagine it for example

```
  public int ChildSize
        {
            get { return childSize; }
            set 
            {
                foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                {
                    child.DesiredSize.Width = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you writing a custom Panel?  More detail in your question please.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are writing a custom panel, which is quite an advanced task.

Your Panel should create overrides for the `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods.

In these methods you should be calling each child's `Measure` and `Arrange` methods passing in appropriate `Size` and `Rect` according your determined childSize and calculated relative positions of each child.

Comment: I knewn this
Which is the property what I have to change? 'cause the RenderSize| DesiredSize is unchangeable

Comment: Have a look at the description of MeasureOverride: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx that's where you define the desired size of your control. You can't just set a property. You need to overwrite the methods MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride just as A.W.Jones mentioned.